# Jquery form validation plugin - temporarily disable and then enable

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using Jquery form validation plugin. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation
All I want is to temporarily disable the form validation while am performing some other operation and after that re-enable the validation on that form.

I used unbind..but then am not able to reenable the validation on that form.

I have 25-30 forms.. so enabling each form again using the rules not possible..Any Suggestion??

Comment: Isn't simply using `$('form').validate();`, the same way you normally initialize enough to re-enable it after unbinding?

Comment: How exactly did you `unbind` the validate plugin?  AFAIK, you can only `unbind` events.